# system.data.common.datarecordinternal error in .net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

// Dropdown data for module_drp

```
    SqlConnection mod_conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=4D\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=tracker;Integrated Security=True");
    mod_conn.Open();
    string selectcmd = @"select testmodule.names from dbo.testmodule";
    SqlCommand cd1 = new SqlCommand(selectcmd,mod_conn);
    //cd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader dr1 = cd1.ExecuteReader();
    module_drp.DataSource = dr1;
    module_drp.DataBind();
    mod_conn.Close();
```

After compiling am getting an error - system.data.common.datarecordinternal

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `DataTextField` property for the `module_drp` in the `.aspx` file with -

```
DataTextField="testmodule.names"
```

Hope this helps :).